# Docker entrypoint can't find file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a very simple docker build file:

```
FROM openjdk:10

ENV JENAVERSION=3.7.0

RUN mkdir /fuseki

RUN wget http://apache.claz.org/jena/binaries/apache-jena-fuseki-$JENAVERSION.tar.gz -P /tmp \
    && tar -zxvf /tmp/apache-jena-fuseki-$JENAVERSION.tar.gz -C /tmp \
    && mv -v /tmp/apache-jena-fuseki-$JENAVERSION/* /fuseki

EXPOSE 3030

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/fuseki/fuseki-server"]
```

I've tried different variations on CMD and ENTRYPOINT, but nothing allows "fuseki-server" to execute.  Always a "No such file or directory" error.  If I manually create an empty container from openjdk:10, and execute each command manually, it works fine.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is the line ending - the entrypoint needs to have LF line ending.
I get the same error when my entrypoint has CLRF line ending.

Comment: This definitely helped me!  On windows, my git client was set up to use CRLF by default, and so building an image locally was failing in exactly this way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I build and run your `Dockerfile`, I get a different error from what you've described.  I see:

```
Can't find jarfile to run
```

If you look at the `fuseki-server` shell script, it's trying to find the jar file relative either to your current directory or to the `$FUSEKI_HOME` environment variable:

```
export FUSEKI_HOME="${FUSEKI_HOME:-$PWD}"

if [ ! -e "$FUSEKI_HOME" ]
then
    echo "$FUSEKI_HOME does not exist" 1>&2
    exit 1
    fi

JAR1="$FUSEKI_HOME/fuseki-server.jar"
JAR2="$FUSEKI_HOME/jena-fuseki-server-*.jar"
JAR=""
```

So if you set the `FUSEKI_HOME` environment variable in your
`Dockerfile`:

```
ENV FUSEKI_HOME=/fuseki
```

Then the container starts up without errors:

```
[2018-06-04 14:02:17] Server     INFO  Apache Jena Fuseki 3.7.0
[2018-06-04 14:02:17] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/fuseki
[2018-06-04 14:02:17] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/run
[2018-06-04 14:02:17] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///run/shiro.ini
[2018-06-04 14:02:18] Server     INFO  Started 2018/06/04 14:02:18 UTC on port 3030
```

Comment: That's really weird.  The package actually includes three ways to start the server, a .jar file (fuseki-server.jar), a bash script (fuseki-server) and a .war file (fuseki-server.war)  I'm trying to run the plain script and getting "/fuseki/fuseki-server: No such file or directory".  I don't know why it would be jumping you right to the .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Wow...  After going through @larsk's suggestion it occurred to me to change the entrypoint to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

and go into the container to see what was actually there.  It turns out that I was accidently overwriting the /fuseki folder with a volume declaration in the compose file I was using.  (facepalm...)